# NoMethodError in Controller #index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backend

So this is my code

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        questions = Question.all 
        render json: questions
    end
end
```

However when i check the route at /questions I am getting

```
undefined method `profession' for #<Question:0x00007f8b31ae3710>
```

and this is where it is reading my error

```
Extracted source (around line #5):

    def index
        questions = Question.all 
        render json: questions <<<< Highlighted Line
    end
end
```

I do have a Profession class but neither are foreign keys of the other. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You could try doing a global search on the entire repository from your editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably somewhere in the view `app/views/questions/`, some code is trying to call `profession` on `question`.

Comment: I found the issue. I changed up my relations and in my serializer it belonged to a profession so thats where my issue was happening.